# Authentication request could not be processed

Tags: symfony

I am implementing a login module where I'm trying to use my database `User` entity for authentication.

I have configured my `security.yml` file as follows to integrate the user entity:

```
providers:
    our_db_provider:
        entity:
           class: UserBundle:User
           property: username
```

But I am facing this error:

> Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem.

Can anyone let me know why this issue is coming?

Comment: Check the Apache's error log... does it show anything out of the ordinary?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a class for authentication that inherit from your UserBundle\Entity\User, you have to specify that the latter is a superclass instead of an entity. Here is an example for User.orm.yaml :

```
UserBundle\Entity\User:
type: mappedSuperclass
[...]
```

More info on Doctrine documentation : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html